# Will pact specification v.4 solve #401 and when will it be released/supported in pact-jvm

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

We're using pact-jvm and due to bug [#401](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/401) we cannot use the eachKeyMappedToAnArrayLike for sub objects which is a real problem for us currently.

I followed the comments in the issue and ended up in the pact v.4 specification that proposed a change to ignore keys in a map: [v4-spec](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/blob/version-4/README.md#ignoring-the-keys-in-a-map).

Will this proposed change fix the bug in eachKeyMappedToAnArrayLike and if so when will v.4 be released/supported by pact-jvm?

If it is not a fix for [#401](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/401), is there one planned? As I said this is crippling us at the moment.

Comment: Hi Joel, StackOverflow isn't a great place to ask a question about particular bugs/issues with Pact.  I think the github repo would be a better place for that.  I'll look into the matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's referencing an issue and asking for when it will be fixed/closed.

Comment: Hi, I understand the point you are making. As long as I can get my question answered somewhere I'll be happy.

Comment: Yeah, I get your concern.  I'm kinda surprised that this slipped through the cracks as we're normally pretty adamant on closing issues.  We will address this ASAP.